# mysql query beautifier

Tags: mysql

I am handling large size MySQL query. so I'm spending my time to beautify the MySQL query to get clear look.I'm using [js beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/), [JSON beautifier](http://jsonlint.com/) those thinks makes my life easy.Is there any such kind of good MYSQL Beautifier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [one](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) supports MySQL, T-SQL, PL/SQL, DB2, SQL.

Comment: This doesn't works on mysql procedure

Comment: Doesn't work for a simple join statement either.

Comment: It's very slow or crashes on large SQLs (few MBs)

Answer (score 4):

I mostly use following link to formate queries

http://sqlformat.appspot.com/